# Is it possible to locate and label matplotlib ticks based on fields that were not used to plot features? Absolute position vs relative reference

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

## Problem Context

I work with manufactured parts that feature a regular grid of pins. These pins are given unique identifiers that reflect their **relative** row and column position on the part.

**e.g. C1:R2** (column 1, row 2)

Finding pins specified in an inspection document is tedious and time consuming without a reference diagram because you have to manually track columns and rows as you work your way into the pin grid.

I'm writing a python script that uses matplotlib to highlight pins based on the pin ID entered in a prompt. I use the **absolute** position of pins, specified in a blueprint, to plot pin points so the plotted positions match what is actually seen on the manufactured part (not to scale).

**e.g. -160.1, 974.9** (actual XY positions in millimeters)

Everything works as intended **EXCEPT** I want to use relative positions for tick locations and tick labels instead of absolute positions. As in: column/row designations instead of X/Y values as axis ticks.

I know it's possible to manually specify plot annotations, but I would prefer a programmatic approach that integrates with part number selection in a prompt. There are multiple part numbers, each with unique pin quantities and positions. Manually coding annotations for each part variant would be almost as tedious as finding the pins without a reference map.

### **TLDR**

Is it possible to **locate and label matplotlib axis ticks based on relative instead of absolute values** when  absolute values are used to plot features?

If that's possible, then how would you implement that in the example script seen below?

## Example Script

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#This script converts lists into a dataframe and plots points using matplotlib

#Setup Lists

ID =  ['C1;R2', 'C2;R2', 'C1;R1', 'C2;R1'] #pin identifier

X = [-160.1, -110.1, -160.1, -110.1] #absolute X

Y = [974.9, 974.9, 924.9, 924.9] #absolute Y

COLUMN = ['1', '2', '1', '2'] #relative X

ROW = ['2', '2', '1', '1'] #relative Y

#Merge Lists

list_of_tuples = list(zip(ID, X, Y, COLUMN, ROW))

#Convert lists to dataframe

Data = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns=['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'COLUMN', 'ROW'])

#Plot points

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(Data['X'], Data['Y'])

#Label Axis

plt.xlabel('X Position')
plt.ylabel('Y Position')

#Set Title

ax.set_title("Reference Plot", size=18)

#Label Points with IDs

Data[['X','Y','ID']].apply(lambda row: ax.text(*row),axis=1)

#Display the plot

plt.show()
```

### Printed Dataframe

```
      ID      X      Y COLUMN ROW
0  C1;R2 -160.1  974.9      1   2
1  C2;R2 -110.1  974.9      2   2
2  C1;R1 -160.1  924.9      1   1
3  C2;R1 -110.1  924.9      2   1
```

### Output

#### Actual Plot

[Plot as written in example script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5r4b.jpg)

#### Desired Plot

[Plot made in Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9ll2.jpg)

Comment: maybe I don't understand problem but why not use `ax.scatter(Data['COLUMN'], Data['ROW'])`

Comment: You could plot it that way, but since COLUMN and ROW are integers, the precision of the XY coordinates are lost. Pins are regularly distributed, but each column is staggered, giving the illusion they follow a diagonal path. The end result is a warped plot that doesn't serve very well as a map for the physical part. This isn't a big deal for 4 points, but quickly becomes an issue when working thousands of regularly placed pins. A geographic information system (GIS) would be better suited for this, but they tend to be complicated, requiring a non-trivial amount of user skill.

Comment: your second image show scales `ROWS 1...2` and `COLUMNS 1..2` which suggests that you don't use `X,Y` . Or maybe you should recalculate `X,Y` to float values in range `1...2`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the `set_ticks()` and `set_ticklabels()` functions.

In my example, I wanted to create 2 x-ticks, one at **x=-160.1** and one at **x=-110.1**.

```
ax.set_xticks([-160.1, -110.1])
```

I also wanted 2 y-ticks, one at **y=924.9** and the other at **y=974.9**.

```
ax.set_yticks([924.9, 974.9])
```

Since those absolute coordinates are meaningless to someone visually inspecting a part, I replaced them with custom relative labels.

```
xlabels = ['1', '2'] # give x-ticks relative column number names instead of blueprint coordinates
ylabels = ['1', '2'] # give y-ticks relative row number names instead of blueprint coordinates
```

Then pass those labels to the `set_ticklabels()` functions.

```
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)
```

## Edited Example Script

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Setup Lists
ID =  ['C1;R2', 'C2;R2', 'C1;R1', 'C2;R1']

X = [-160.1, -110.1, -160.1, -110.1]

Y = [974.9, 974.9, 924.9, 924.9]

COLUMN = ['1', '2', '1', '2']

ROW = ['2', '2', '1', '1']

#Merge Lists
list_of_tuples = list(zip(ID, X, Y, COLUMN, ROW))

#Convert lists to dataframe
Data = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples,
                  columns=['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'COLUMN', 'ROW'])

#Plot points
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(Data['X'], Data['Y'])

#Label Axis
plt.xlabel('COLUMN')
plt.ylabel('ROW')

#Set Title
ax.set_title("Reference Plot", size=18)

#Label Points with IDs
Data[['X','Y','ID']].apply(lambda row: ax.text(*row),axis=1)

#Define custom tick locations
ax.set_xticks([-160.1, -110.1]) #I want x ticks at these blueprint coordinates
ax.set_yticks([924.9, 974.9]) #I want y ticks at these blueprint coordinates

#Create custom axis tick labels
xlabels = ['1', '2'] # give x-ticks relative column number names instead of blueprint coordinates
ylabels = ['1', '2'] # give y-ticks relative row number names instead of blueprint coordinates

#Apply new labels to custom tick locations
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```